# How do I install Perl's Parse::Lex for ActivePerl?

Tags: perl, package, activeperl

Hi I am using ActivePerl 5.10.1 on Win XP.

I can't find **Lex** package from the PPM list.

Can I install other package to enable Parse::Lex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do believe ParseLex is in the base set of packages in PPM. Try:

```
> ppm install ParseLex
```

from the command line? You'll need to set the http_proxy environment variable if behind a proxy, you can do it for that session only by issuing this before the command above:

```
> set http_proxy=http://host:port/
```

e.g.

```
> set http_proxy=http://10.100.9.10:8080/
```

If using the GUI... I believe the set of packages displayed by default is the installed set so you'd be searching that for Lex. Click View -> All Packages if this is the case.

Comment: I searched and found it from GUI. And I tried to installed it from command line. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Aye, the default view of packages has caught me out a couple times in a new installation...