# Trying to install MinGW and Tk for Perl on Windows 7

Tags: perl, mingw, tk-toolkit, perltk, mingw32

So... I have been trying to get this working for several weeks now. I can install MinGW through the .exe, but no-matter what I do I can't seem to get make support or ppm install MinGW to work in such a way that my compilation of Tk-804.029 will correctly use the 'make' command.

(Installing a Perl Module:

1. perl MakeFile.PL - Works fine
2. make or dmake - I can't get MinGW to properly associate Make or DMake (Can't find the correct .exe in the MinGW/bin directory either... I've tried using the -32bit mingw32-make.exe but that brings up errors to do with the compiled header files.

)

ppm install MinGW also doesn't work, seems to think it can't find the package. So I am at a loss. System is running Windows 7 on a x64 setup.

Comment: With the `ppm install` approach, you may be behind a proxy. If that's the case you need to set the proxy first. How? See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712354/how-do-i-install-perls-parselex-for-activeperl).

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't think it's a proxy issue though since I can download Tk itself through PPM install, just not MinGW. (And if downloaded it doesnt install for the above reasons; the lack of a Windows 7 compatible Make tool that registers with PPM)

Comment: Any reason why you don't use a prepared distribution, such as ActiveState's?

Comment: Active Perl Tkx works fine, unfortunately I am trying to get a third party script running which uses the original Tcl::Tk modules, the code I am writing will be sent off to be used by someone else who only uses Tcl::Tk. Otherwise yes, I have some other code that runs fine on Tkx from ActiveState.

Comment: I am affected by this issue too. Third-party script, Win 7 64 bit and need to install Tk and WinGW. Not easy...

Answer (score 2):

What perl are you using? You could try 
    perl Makefile.PL MAKE=dmake

or

```
ppm install http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/Tk.ppd 
ppm install dmake MinGW
ppm upgrade dmake MinGW
```

or download from
    http://ppm4.activestate.com/author/MINGW.html
Or try http://strawberryperl.com/

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using Strawberry Perl if possible (and for Perl on Windows in general), as it will give you a working dmake out of the box. I don't have Windows 7, but Tk installs fine from CPAN using Strawberry 5.10 on Windows XP.